# IPython: Modify cells from custom wrapper kernel

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to creating custom wrapper notebooks and I'm trying to create/replace a cell's contents from within a custom kernel definition. My use case is that I can't use custom magics (from what I read on the web) with wrapper notebooks so I'm looking to create my own workaround for this within the do_execute method for my kernel.

I have found that you can use something like this within an IPython Python notebook to edit/create a cell:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.set_next_cell('Test')
```

When I try including that in the do_execute definition for my kernel class, I get the following error when I try to run a cell in my active notebook kernel:

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 212, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 370, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\Dropbox\idl_code\echokernel.py", line 16, in do_execute
    ip.set_next_input('test string!')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_next_input'
```

**My question is:
Does anyone know of a simple way that you can modify cells within a custom wrapper notebook definition?**

I have been looking around the web in different places, but haven't been able to find a clear, simple example for how to do this. Here is my kernel code that I am using, which I got from [here](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrapperkernels.html) and modified a bit:

```
from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
from IPython import get_ipython

class EchoKernel(Kernel):
    implementation = 'Echo'
    implementation_version = '1.0'
    language = 'no-op'
    language_version = '0.1'
    language_info = {'mimetype': 'text/plain'}
    banner = "Echo kernel - as useful as a parrot"

    def do_execute(self, code, silent, store_history=True, user_expressions=None,
                   allow_stdin=False):

        ip = get_ipython()
        ip.set_next_input('test string!')

        if not silent:
            stream_content = {'name': 'stdout', 'text': code}
            self.send_response(self.iopub_socket, 'stream', stream_content)

        return {'status': 'ok',
                # The base class increments the execution count
                'execution_count': self.execution_count,
                'payload': [],
                'user_expressions': {},
               }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
    IPKernelApp.launch_instance(kernel_class=EchoKernel)
```

Here is my kernel JSON definition as well:

```
{"argv":["python","-m","echokernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name":"Echo"
}
```

Comment: You need to use one level lower - IPython's shell object isn't available when you're making your own kernel. Add a `set_next_input` payload ([docs](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#payloads-deprecated)) to the 'payloads' field in the return dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! That's exactly what I was looking for and does the trick.

Comment: Hi, could you write an answer with your insights from this work?